# How to split a String in a multidimensional Array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, multidimensional-array, split

I have an multidimensional Array in Ruby, like this:

`[["2013-08-22 13:23:12 +0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22 14:25:12 +0123" , 123, 1]]`

I would like to split the string in the first array position and the time to hours, minutes and seconds (and convert these to integers), so it will become:

`[["2013-08-22", 13, 23, 12, "+0212", 100, 1], [.....]]`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: My question is, how did you manage to arrive at your starting point? Maybe having a string representation of a datetime in a multidimensional array could be avoided and much more elegantly implemented.

Comment: These are data generated by a fax machine and are saved in a json format. In total I have an array with 52000 of the above arrays in it...and I have to convert them into the requested format, so I can process them.

Comment: So you have JSON -> multidimensional array -> array you want -> processed array. Assuming you're getting the JSON from an API, I'd think you can create a Fax client that skips some of the middle steps.

Comment: Please mark the answer that you found the most helpful as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like more readability, I suggest this:

```
require 'date'
array = [["2013-08-22 13:23:12 +0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22 14:25:12 +0123" , 123, 1]]
array.map do |date_time, a, b|
  date_time = DateTime.parse(date_time)

  [
    date_time.strftime('%F'), date_time.hour, date_time.min,
    date_time.sec, date_time.strftime('%z'), a, b
  ]
end
```

It makes it very clear what each element of the resulting array is. You should replace `a` and `b` with meaningful names if you have them.

Comment: This looks very nice, although you are losing the `"+0212"` string. BTW, you need to change every `d` with `date_time`. :)

Comment: Upvoting this one. Ruby has an canonical way to parse a datetime, so we should use it, not reinvent it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you guys know of a nicer way to do `date_time.to_date.to_s` as well as `date_Time.zone.to_s.gsub(':', '')`. Those were two pieces that I didn't really like. It might even be best to pull them out into separate variables before creating the return value.

Comment: Sure, you can use [formats](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime). `date_time.strftime('%F')` and `date_time.strftime('%z')`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
[["2013-08-22 13:23:12 +0212", 100, 1],
 ["2013-09-22 14:25:12 +0123" , 123, 1]].

   map do |arr|
     arr.shift.split(/[: ]/) + arr # first position only
     # ⇓ this will convert hours, minutes and seconds  to integers
     # arr.shift.split(/[: ]/).map { |e| e[/\A\d+\z/] ? e.to_i : e } + arr
     # ⇓ this would work for all strings
     # arr.flat_map { |e| e.is_a?(String) ? e.split(/[: ]/) : e }
   end
#⇒ [
#  [0] [
#    [0] "2013-08-22",
#    [1] "13",
#    [2] "23",
#    [3] "12",
#    [4] "+0212",
#    [5] 100,
#    [6] 1
#  ],
#  [1] [
#    [0] "2013-09-22",
#    [1] "14",
#    [2] "25",
#    [3] "12",
#    [4] "+0123",
#    [5] 123,
#    [6] 1
#  ]
# ]
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Is it possible to convert hours, minutes and seconds to integer (as requested by OP) in a simple and concise way? (unlike my [not-so-pretty solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214780/6136634))

Comment: Just wanted to thank you all, and especially you, as this post helped me the most!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (converting hours, minutes and seconds to integers):

```
arr = [["2013-08-22 13:23:12 +0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22 14:25:12 +0123" , 123, 1]]

arr.map do |item|
  date, time, zone = item[0].split.map { |e| e.split(":") }
  [date, time.map(&:to_i), zone, item[1..-1]].flatten
end
#=> [["2013-08-22", 13, 23, 12, "+0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22", 14, 25, 12, "+0123", 123, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive way. ref [@mudasobwa answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214905/3275798)

```
arr = [["2013-08-22 13:23:12 +0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22 14:25:12 +0123" , 123, 1]]
arr.map {|e| e[0].split(/[ :]/) + e[1..-1] } 
#=> [["2013-08-22", "13", "23", "12", "+0212", 100, 1], ["2013-09-22", "14", "25", "12", "+0123", 123, 1]]
```

Comment: Also taken from mudasobwa answer: `arr.map {|e| e[0].split(/[ :]/).map { |e| e[/\A\d+\z/] ? e.to_i : e } + e[1..-1] }` to convert hours, minutes and seconds to integer (as requested by OP).